# Regular expression to convert 2020-03-02T13:40:03.000Z into DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS

Tags: javascript, regex, date

Consider the DateTime `2020-03-02T13:40:03.000Z`

I want to convert it into `02-03-2020 13:40:03`.

The following function converts YYYYMMDD into  DD/MM/YYYY.

```
  const convertDateToDDMMYYYY = (date) => {
    const newDate = date.replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/g, '$1-$2-$3');
    return newDate;
  }
```

How can we ignore the `T` and the `.000Z` suffix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
.replace(/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\.\d+Z$/, '$3-$2-$1 $4')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lFFGy7/1)

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d{4})` - Group 1: year
- `-(\d{2})-` - hyphen, Group 2: month, then a hyphen
- `(\d{2})` - Group 3: day
- `T` - a T (just matched, not captured!)
- `(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})` - Group 4: time part
- `\.` - a dot
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `Z` - a `Z` char
- `$` - end of string.

See the JS demo:

```js
const convertDateToDDMMYYYY = (date) => {
    return date.replace(/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\.\d+Z$/, '$3-$2-$1 $4');
  }

console.log(convertDateToDDMMYYYY("2020-03-02T13:40:03.000Z"))
```

Comment: This is gorgeous , can you please refer me to a good tutorial to learn from ?

Comment: @JAN I do not know your level of regex knowledge :) so that I can only suggest doing all lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/), reading through [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (with many other links to great online resources), and the community SO post called [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). Also, [rexegg.com](http://rexegg.com) is worth having a look at.

Comment: If I could I would have given you +400000000000000000000

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the result you want by using the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object and then extracting each of the parts:

```js
const date = new Date('2020-03-02T13:40:03.000Z');

const sdate =
  [('0' + date.getUTCDate()).slice(-2),
   ('0' + (date.getUTCMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
   date.getUTCFullYear()
  ].join('-') +
  ' ' +
  [('0' + date.getUTCHours()).slice(-2),
   ('0' + date.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2),
   ('0' + date.getUTCSeconds()).slice(-2)
  ].join(':');

console.log(sdate);
```

Comment: Thanks , but I want only regex.

Comment: @JAN any particular reason? The advantage of using the inbuilt `Date` object is that it will work with far more date formats than just `2020-03-02T13:40:03.000Z`

Comment: @Nick—you shouldn't use the built–in parser for anything other than the 2 supported formats, so it still has to be customised to parse each different format.

Comment: @RobG I was referring to the fact that both the supported `ISO8601` and `RFC 2822` formats have optional parts, allowing for more flexibility in specifying datetime values.